# Issue with stacking JS Sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm trying to have 3 stacking JS sliders, but the last two aren't showing up. Any idea why? :(

http://pastebin.com/ic8VYpXS

Comment: IDs **MUST** be unique. And jQuery 1.3.2??

Comment: Yes, I just changed it but it didn't work either, so should I duplicate the css and just add 1/2/3 to the ids?

Comment: You can use classes if you're going to have multiple elements. That way you won't have to duplicate the CSS, that's pretty much the main point of classes. :}

Comment: One more question though, how can I center the logo? I can't for the life of me make it work.